Showing $\lim_{x\to \infty}\ln\frac{x^2+1}{e^x}=-\infty$.
I have this limit $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\ln\left(\dfrac{x^2+1}{e^x}\right)$$
We know that $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{x^2+1}{e^x}=0^+$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\ln(x)=-\infty$$
Hence $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\ln\left(\dfrac{x^2+1}{e^x}\right)=-\infty$$
I know the final result is right but I  wanted to know how precise this reasoning is and if it is correct what is exactly the theorem that we are using here for the limit of the composition.

Hello, welcome to the site. Regarding "$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^2+1}{e^x}=0^+$" note that the limit is equal to zero (a number), and $\text{limit}=\text{number}^+$ doesn't make much sense.

because $\ln(x)$ is not defined on the left of $0$, that's why I wrote $0^+$

This is true since $\ln(x)$ is continuous to the right at $0$.

I add that in general, essentially, when a function is continuous in a neighborhood of $x_0$, then "you can bring the limit inside".

Yes this is correct by this theorem:

Limit Laws for Composite Functions

As an alternative, by squeeze theorem, we can use that eventually
$$\ln\left(\dfrac{x^2+1}{e^x}\right) \le \ln\left(\dfrac{e^{\frac x2}}{e^x}\right)=\ln\left(e^{-\frac x2}\right)=-\frac x 2 \to -\infty$$

what about limit of $f\circ g(x)$ where $ \lim_{x\to a}g(x)=+\infty$ and  $ \lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=l$ can we always say that  $ \lim_{x\to a}f\circ g(x)=l$

Yes, this is also true!

I will proceed accordingly with the OP's method.
Let $$L=\lim_{x\to \infty}\ln\left(\frac{x^{2}+1}{e^{x}}\right)$$
Now at $x\to \infty$ we can say that
$\frac{x^{2}+1}{e^{x}}$ is of the form of $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$
Now here I will apply a trick.
$$\implies L=\lim_{x\to \infty}\ln\left(\frac{x^{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)}{e^{x}}\right)$$
$$\implies L=\lim_{x\to \infty}\ln\left(\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)}{\frac{e^{x}}{x^{2}}}\right)$$
$\implies L=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left[\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)-\ln\left(\frac{e^{x}}{x^{2}}\right)\right]$
Now at $x\to \infty$ $\frac{e^{x}}{x^{2}}$ is of the form of $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$
After applying L-Hospital's rule, you will get
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{e^{x}}{x^{2}}\to \infty$$
Therefore finally you will get
$$L=0-\lim_{x\to \infty}\ln\left(\frac{e^{x}}{x^{2}}\right)$$
Therefore you will get the result to be $-\infty$ because $\ln(\infty)\to \infty$

More simply we can apply l’Hospital to the expression $(x^2+1)/e^x>0$.

This does not answer the question. OP knows how to solve the limit and he's asking clarification on why we can bring the limit inside the logarithm
